# How find this $\lim_{x\to 1} (\frac{x^x-x}{\ln{x}-x+1}+2)/( x-1)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find  the limit

$$I=\lim_{x\to 1}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{x^x-x}{\ln{x}-x+1}+2\right)}{x-1}$$

I want let $x-1=t$
$$I=\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{(t+1)^{t+1}-(t+1)}{\ln{(t+1)}-t}+2}{t}=\lim_{t\to  0}\dfrac{(t+1)^{t+1}-(t+1)+2\ln{(t+1)}-2t}{t(\ln{(t+1)}-t)}=\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{(t+1)^{t+1}+2\ln{(t+1)}-3t-1}{-\dfrac{t^3}{2}}$$

I have  solve this result $-\dfrac{7}{3}$by hand ,is true ?

Comment: l'Hopital's rule ?

Comment: The tag (analysis) is too broad, as its wiki says. I retagged. Also, the titles should not up take so much vertical space: [see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730/147263).

Answer (score 1):

Taylor series, built at $x=1$ could work $$\log(x)=(x-1)-\frac{1}{2} (x-1)^2+\frac{1}{3} (x-1)^3+O\left((x-1)^4\right)$$ $$\log(x)-x+1=-\frac{1}{2} (x-1)^2+\frac{1}{3} (x-1)^3+O\left((x-1)^4\right)$$ $$x^x-x=(x-1)^2+\frac{1}{2} (x-1)^3+O\left((x-1)^4\right)$$ Combining the pieces $$\frac{\left(\frac{x^x-x}{\ln{x}-x+1}+2\right)}{x-1}=-\frac{7}{3}-\frac{11 }{9}(x-1)-\frac{83}{135} (x-1)^2+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

it can be simplified to ${\frac {{x}^{x}-3\,x+2\,\ln  \left( x \right) +2}{ \left( \ln  \left( 
x \right) -x+1 \right)  \left( x-1 \right) }}
$ and now you can use L'Hospital